# copying xpath of modal window

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am new to this community.
I am trying to execute  xpath of login option from a modal window but unable to do it.i tried all combination of xpath but didn't get the result. website:https://yappily.com/
 Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
public class Web_Url
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {   
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files\\selenium drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
             WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.get("https://yappily.com/");         
            driver.manage().window().maximize();      
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sell-login']/div/div/div[1]/p/a")).click();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Please Go through [ask]

Comment: getting error in last line:at yappily_TestCases.Web_Url.main(Web_Url.java:20)

Comment: What's the error? Post full stack trace

Comment: Sorry for asking but i don't know how to post full stack trace,will you please help me out?

Comment: getting error on last line:driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sell-login']/div/div/div[1]/p/a")).click();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Login Modal box takes some time to load after clicking Login. So you have to handle the wait either explicitly/implicitly. You can read more on [Selenium Wait in here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) or [Here](http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html).

I have used [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to achieve the same

This code will solve your problem

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://yappily.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement fbLogin = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='sell-login']/div/div/div[1]/p/a")));

    fbLogin.click();
```

Also you have to work on your `Xpath`. Down the line these kind of xpath won't be a much of help. Read about [relative xpaths](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) and [css selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) as well

Answer (score 0):

Add Implicit wait after login button clicked.
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitwait(5,Timeunit.second); This will solve.